# How to customize an expandable list in a layout in android?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, fullscreen, expandablelistview

I am facing a problem regarding expandable List in a linear layout. I have an XML where I am trying to show
1. A Title.
2. While clicking that title one can expand the predefined list and make a choice from that list

But the main problem is, while I am adding a footer image in the Linear layout, it gets beneath the Title. and leaves a huge blank space beneath itself. But while I expand the list by clicking the List, than the footer remains at the last leaving no vacant space behind on the screen.

I want the footer to always at the bottom of the screen not leaving any blank space so that it looks the entire screen is covered by the linear layout.

Please help me guys!. I am surly in a fixed.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/sc1">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@layout/layout"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingRight="7dip"
    android:paddingLeft="7dip"
    android:paddingTop="5dip"
    android:background="#224782"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:id = "@+id/l1">

    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@layout/mybutton"
    android:padding="5dip"
    android:layout_marginBottom="7dip"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >  


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:onClick="openMinimized"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:shadowColor="#7F000000"
        android:shadowDx="1"
        android:shadowDy="1"
        android:shadowRadius="6"
        android:layout_weight=".7"
        android:paddingLeft="15dip"
        android:textSize="28dip"
        android:text="@string/start" />

    <ToggleButton 
        android:id="@+id/togglebutton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/bgtoggle"
        android:button="@null"
        android:textOff=""
        android:textOn=""
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>


    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@layout/layout"
    android:padding="5dip"
    android:layout_marginBottom="7dip"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtBoot"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@layout/mybutton"
        android:text="@string/sob"
        android:shadowColor="#7F000000"
        android:shadowDx="1"
        android:shadowDy="1"
        android:shadowRadius="6"
        android:textColor="#FFFAFA"
        android:textSize="24dip" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lboot"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@layout/layout"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtCheck"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:text="Always start the Monitoring on Boot"
            android:layout_weight=".001"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dip"
            android:textSize="16dip" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox3"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txtCheck"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dip"
            android:checked="true"
            android:button="@null"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/select_"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dip"
            android:paddingLeft="10dip"
            android:layout_weight=".999"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:text="" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtSpeed"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:background="@layout/mybutton"
        android:textColor="#FFFAFA"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:shadowColor="#7F000000"
        android:shadowDx="1"
        android:shadowDy="1"
        android:shadowRadius="6"
        android:drawableRight= "@drawable/arrow"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:text="@string/speed" 
        android:textSize="24dip"/>
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@layout/layout"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:id="@+id/radio_group_speed">

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton18"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dip"        
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:button="@null"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/white"
        android:textSize="16dip" 
        android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:background="@layout/radio_layout_green"
        android:text="Speed in MB/s"
        android:textAlignment="textStart"/>

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton16"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dip"        
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:button="@null"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/white"
        android:textSize="16dip" 
        android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:background="@layout/radio_layout"
        android:text="Speed in Mb/s"
        android:textAlignment="textStart"/>

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dip"        
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:button="@null"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/white"
        android:textSize="16dip" 
        android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:background="@layout/radio_layout_green"
        android:text="Speed in KB/s"
        android:textAlignment="textStart"/>



    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dip"
        android:text="Speed in Kb/s"
        android:button="@null"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/white"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:background="@layout/radio_layout"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:textSize="16dip" />


    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton19"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dip"
        android:text="Speed in Combo (KB/s and MB/s)"
        android:button="@null"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
        android:background="@layout/radio_layout_green"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/white"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:textSize="16dip" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton17"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dip"
        android:text="Speed in Combo (Kb/s and Mb/s)"
        android:button="@null"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/white"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:checked="true"
        android:background="@layout/radio_layout"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:textSize="16dip" />

    </RadioGroup>
    </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@layout/layout"
    android:padding="5dip"
    android:layout_marginBottom="7dip"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtSize"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:shadowColor="#7F000000"
        android:shadowDx="1"
        android:shadowDy="1"
        android:shadowRadius="6"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
        android:textColor="#FFFAFA"
        android:drawableRight= "@drawable/arrow"
        android:text="@string/display" 
        android:background="@layout/mybutton"
        android:textSize="24dip"/>

    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@layout/layout"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:id="@+id/radio_group_size">

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio10"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dip"
        android:text="10pt" 
        android:textSize="16dip"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:button="@null"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/white"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:background="@layout/radio_layout_green"
        android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:checked="true"
        android:textAlignment="textStart"/>

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio11"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dip"
        android:button="@null"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/white"
        android:text="11pt"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
        android:background="@layout/radio_layout"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:textSize="16dip" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio12"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dip"
        android:button="@null"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/white"
        android:text="12pt"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:background="@layout/radio_layout_green"
        android:textSize="16dip" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio13"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dip"
        android:button="@null"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/white"
        android:text="13pt"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
        android:background="@layout/radio_layout"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:textSize="16dip" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio14"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dip"
        android:button="@null"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/white"
        android:text="14pt"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:background="@layout/radio_layout_green"
        android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:textSize="16dip" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio15"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dip"
        android:button="@null"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/white"
        android:text="15pt"
        android:background="@layout/radio_layout"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:textSize="16dip" />

    </RadioGroup>
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtColor"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#FFFAFA"
        android:shadowColor="#7F000000"
        android:shadowDx="1"
        android:shadowDy="1"
        android:shadowRadius="6"
        android:drawableRight= "@drawable/arrow"
        android:background="@layout/mybutton"
        android:text="@string/color" 
        android:textSize="24dip"/>

    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@layout/layout"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:id="@+id/radio_group_color">

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioWhite"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dip"
        android:button="@null"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/white"
        android:text="White" 
        android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="16dip"
        android:background="@layout/radio_layout_green"
        android:textAlignment="textStart"/>

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioYellow"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dip"
        android:button="@null"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/white"
        android:text="Yellow" 
        android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="16dip"
        android:background="@layout/radio_layout"
        android:textAlignment="textStart"/>

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioAquamarine"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dip"
        android:button="@null"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/white"
        android:text="Aquamarine" 
        android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="16dip"
        android:background="@layout/radio_layout_green"
        android:textAlignment="textStart"/>

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioAzure"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dip"
        android:button="@null"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/white"
        android:text="Azure" 
        android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="16dip"
        android:background="@layout/radio_layout"
        android:textAlignment="textStart"/>

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioBlack"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dip"
        android:button="@null"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/white"
        android:text="Black"
        android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:background="@layout/radio_layout_green"
        android:textSize="16dip" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioBlue"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dip"
        android:button="@null"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/white"
        android:text="Blue"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:background="@layout/radio_layout"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:textSize="16dip" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioRed"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dip"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:button="@null"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/white"
        android:text="Red"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:background="@layout/radio_layout_green"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:textSize="16dip" />


    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioJade"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:button="@null"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/white"
        android:layout_height="40dip"
        android:text="Jade"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:background="@layout/radio_layout"
        android:textSize="16dip" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioBrightGreen"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:button="@null"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/white"
        android:layout_height="40dip"
        android:text="Bright Green"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
        android:checked="true"
        android:background="@layout/radio_layout_green"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:textSize="16dip" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioGreen"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:button="@null"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/white"
        android:layout_height="40dip"
        android:text="Green"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:background="@layout/radio_layout"
        android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:textSize="16dip" />

    </RadioGroup>
    </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@layout/layout"
    android:padding="5dip"
    android:layout_marginBottom="7dip"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textPosition"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:shadowColor="#002E63"
        android:shadowDx="1"
        android:shadowDy="1"
        android:shadowRadius="6"
        android:text="@string/position" 
        android:drawableRight= "@drawable/arrow"
        android:textColor="#FFFAFA"
        android:background="@layout/mybutton"
        android:textSize="24dip"/>

    <RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:id="@+id/radio_group_position">

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioTopRight"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dip"
        android:text="Top Right Corner" 
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
        android:button="@null"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/white"
        android:textSize="16dip"
        android:checked="true"
        android:background="@layout/radio_layout_green"
        android:textAlignment="textStart"/>

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioTopLeft"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dip"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:text="Top Left Corner"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:button="@null"
        android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/white"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:background="@layout/radio_layout"
        android:textSize="16dip" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioBottomRight"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dip"
        android:text="Bottom Right Corner"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:button="@null"
        android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:background="@layout/radio_layout_green"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/white"
        android:textSize="16dip" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioBottomLeft"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dip"
        android:text="Bottom Left Corner"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:button="@null"
        android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:background="@layout/radio_layout"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/white"
        android:textSize="16dip" />

    </RadioGroup>
    </LinearLayout>

     <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/rlbtm"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:background="@layout/layout"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center|bottom"
            android:layout_marginBottom="7dip"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >


         <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center"
            android:src="@drawable/my_logo_1" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: paste your code ,your activity code and layout file

Comment: Ok, I am adding the xml code in the question..@ andrewww

Answer (score 0):

If you are thinking it is a problem in your layout Design then use Weight , it can solve your problem .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
     android:weightSum="5" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/home"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/home1"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/home2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/home3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/home4"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>
```